# Push destination error after doing a git clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

I just cloned a repository and I was able to to do a `git commit -m`, but I can't do a `git push` as I receive an error:

> No configured push destination.
>   Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using
>
> `git remote add <name> <url>`
>
> and then push using the remote name
>
> `git push <name>`

I am an admin of the repository but it was initially someone else's repo. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: I get this:fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @user3140562 How did you clone this repo? What is the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: @user3140562 - Very weird. These errors should not happen on a cloned repo.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is late but the problem was that I was doing the git calls in the directory where the repo was being stored, not the repo itself. For example, if the repo was called Repo and it was stored in Folder, I was calling `git push` in Folder, not Repo.